# TVOutManager working on Simulator, but not on a device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to project my iPhone app on an external display. I tried TVOutManager, It works perfect on the simulator (I turned on the TV Out Option, and have tested iOS from 4.0 to 4.3). However, when I install the app on my iPhone4, it doesn't work neither on an external display nor on a TV. Am I missing something or there are some special requirements for the cable or accessory?

```
#import "TVOutManager.h"
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
    [[TVOutManager sharedInstance] startTVOut];
    .....
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[TVOutManager sharedInstance] startTVOut];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Some apps on the App Store output to the TV.  Have you checked with one of them that you cable setup is working?

Comment: I noticed that some projectors won't display through TVOutManager. In the end, a DELL projector and iPhone-to-RCA cable did the trick. Try either the iPhone-to-HDMI or RCA cable. As Benoit points out, you can also make sure that your cable runs correctly, for example with the Netflix app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use a high quality VGA-cable, or a short one. Short one is better of course.

Trick to make it work, when it's not:

1. Connect projector cable
2. Open app
3. All well? Stop and pet your back, if not continue:
4. Kill the application with a double-home-button-death-tap
5. Restart the application (with the cable still connected)

This usually solves the problem for us, step 3-5 might need some iterations.